# Passing two parameters to consume a web service from android

Tags: android, web-services

How to pass two parameters to consume a web service from android by the method SOAP.
I have tried,but i am unable to consume that web service from android.

Suggestions?

This is the exact web service which  i am trying to consume "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx"

The input values for this web service are

FromDate : 01/01/2012

ToDate : 07/07/2012

**Sources for reference**

**Webservice_.java**

```
public class Webservice_ extends Activity 
{

public static String rslt="";    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final  AlertDialog ad=new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();

     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


public void onClick(View arg0) 
{

try
{ 
EditText ed1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText ed2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2); 

int a=Integer.parseInt(ed1.getText().toString());
int b=Integer.parseInt(ed2.getText().toString()); rslt="START";

Caller c=new Caller(); 

c.FromDate=a;
c.ToDate=b; 

c.ad=ad;

c.join();
c.start();

while(rslt=="START") 
{
try {
Thread.sleep(10); 

}catch(Exception ex) {

 }
} ad.setTitle(+a +b);
ad.setMessage(rslt); 

}catch(Exception ex) {
ad.setTitle("Error!"); ad.setMessage(ex.toString());
}
ad.show();  
} });
}}
```

**CallSoap.java**

```
public class CallSoap 
{
public  final String METHOD_NAME = "GetTMSChart"; 
public  final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
public final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GetTMSChart";
public  final String URL = "http://54.251.60.177/TMSOrdersService/TMSDetails.asmx";

public CallSoap() 
{ 

}
public String Call(int FromDate,int ToDate)
{

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,SOAP_ACTION);
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();

pi.setName("FromDate");
pi.setValue(FromDate);

pi.setType(Date.class);
request.addProperty(pi);

pi=new PropertyInfo();

pi.setName("ToDate");
pi.setValue(ToDate);
pi.setType(Date.class);
request.addProperty(pi);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
Object response=null;
try
{
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
  response = envelope.getResponse();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
response=exception.toString();
}
return response.toString();
}  
}
```

**Caller.java**

```
 public class Caller extends Thread  

{ 
public CallSoap cs;
public int FromDate,ToDate;
protected AlertDialog ad; 

public void run()
{
 try
 {
 cs=new CallSoap();
 String resp=cs.Call(FromDate, ToDate);

 Webservice_.rslt=resp;
 }
 catch(Exception ex)
{
 Webservice_.rslt=ex.toString();
}    
}
}
```

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: public String Call(int FromDate,int ToDate) should be public String Call(date FromDate,date ToDate) or like wise

Answer (score 1):

The core code would be something like following in your javafile...

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);
PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("a");
pi.setValue(a);
pi.setType(Integer.class);
request.addProperty(pi);
pi=new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("b");
pi.setValue(b);
pi.setType(Integer.class);
request.addProperty(pi);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
```

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap) is complete one by one step to produce the same.

Hope this helps.

On top of that you can [see](http://www.android.net/forum/beginning-developers/78662-how-call-net-asmx-webservice-android.html) this link,

Thanks,
Jigar

Comment: i have followed your suggestion and i got some new issues, can you please make me clear?

Comment: Actually i am passing the input values as date ie(01/01/2012 and 07/07/2012),but i am getting the issues as java.lang.NumberFormat exception

Comment: why public String Call(int FromDate,int ToDate) you are setting them as int??????????

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16497/discussion-between-rohith-and-jigar-pandya)